# beta testers on google play to see each other's reviews

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, beta-testing

I have a group of beta testers for my android app. I am using Google Play for that (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en ).

I want my beta testers to be able to talk to each other. I can't seem to use the `Rate & Review` section because testers can't see each other's comments apparently (I read that somewhere). So is there a way to let my testers view each other's comments. Of course, I still need for production users to not see these testers' comments.